# Transfer indexpath.row to a new view controller?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing, swift2

I have an array that stores information for one table view controller called levels array. When you click on a cell in levelsArray it presents a second table view controller. The `prepareForSegue` method in the `FirstTableViewController` looks like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
            if (segue.identifier == "Load View") {
                // pass data to next view
                let indexpath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
                let NavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
                let DestinationViewController = NavigationController.topViewController as! AnswerTableViewController
                var ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo : [Answer]
                var ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements = levelsArray.map( { $0.AnswersArray })
                ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo = ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements[indexpath.row]
                let selectedLevel: List? = levelsArray[indexpath.row]
                DestinationViewController.ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements = ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo
                DestinationViewController.selectedLevel = selectedLevel
            }
        }
```

My question is how can I get [indexpath.row] to a new view controller that adds elements to the second view controller.
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you naming your variables with uppercase first? You might want to read this: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#naming

Comment: can you use indexpath.row value in second vc

Comment: Don't think so, can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the `destinationViewController` isn a `UINavigationController`; it's your own `UIViewController` subclass, `MyViewController`. Make sure `MyViewController` has a method or property that the sender can access, and use that to pass in `indexPath.row`.